# Multiple body backgrounds

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to figure out a way to have multiple background colors on a project i am working on. The design is made with 4 colors on the background. 1 for the header and content, 1 for the sidebar and 1 for each of the 2 footer sections.
Setting the background-color on those is easy as pie - the problem comes when i need to make the colors actually grow outside of the container (match the width of the browser) but still have a max-width of the container itself for 940px.

I am using Twitter Bootstrap 3 as the boilerplate for the project.

Any suggestions?

[image: Example markup]

Comment: How do you envisage these backgrounds colours on other screen sizes, such as tablets, mobiles etc?

Comment: Please post the relevant CSS code :)

Comment: @MartinBean On tablets, mobile etc, it switches to just one solid background color - it is only on desktop the colors are as stated.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 there currently is no real css to show as i am not sure where to begin sort of speak. so there is only the markup from bootstrap basicly.

Comment: Is a 1 pixel GIF, repeated vertically, an option if you split your page into a top half and a bottom half?

Comment: @MartinBean i can use images, no problem. But how would i go about splitting the page up with bootstrap containers?

Comment: I think you’re thinking you’re restricted to using *just* Bootstrap mark-up on your page, and you’re not. As per http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#customizing, create a style sheet to hold custom styles. You can then place styles for your top and bottom containers, which would have a `background-image` tiled vertically.

Comment: @MartinBean Do you have any quick thoughts/example of how you would make the container to do this? And how you would do the css?

Comment: Just a simple, full-width `<div>` for the top half and another for the bottom half, with your `background-image` applied on both will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If background images are an option, then you could split your page into a top part and a bottom part, and then apply background images to those containers.

Your HTML would look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    …
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main-wrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <header class="header" role="banner">
          …
        </header>
        <div class="row">
          <section class="col-8" role="main">
            …
          </section>
          <aside class="col-4" role="complementary">
            …
          </aside>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer" role="contentinfo">
      <div class="container">
        …
      </div>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

And then you would just create styles for your `.main-wrapper` and `.footer` that applies your tiling background image to them.

Create a new style sheet called **application.css** and load it after **bootstrap.min.css**, and place the following CSS rules in it:

```
.main-wrapper {
    background: url(../img/main-bg.png) repeat-y 50% 0;
}

.footer {
    background: url(../img/footer-bg.png) repeat-y 50% 0;
}
```